# Reading .csv file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just trying to read a .csv file which I saved in a directory. 
At first I give

```
path="E:\\Google\\Google Stock Market Data - google_stock_data.csv"
```

It is interpreted successfully. I move to next line. And give the command

```
file=open(path)
```

Then it gives the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    file=open(path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\Google\\Google Stock Market Data - google_stock_data.csv'
```

Comment: Try using raw string Ex: `path=r"E:\Google\Google Stock Market Data - google_stock_data.csv"`

Comment: Alternatively, try using single forward slashes, and double check the path is correct

Comment: @Rakesh OP is using double slashes (that escape the potential control character `'\G'`). Using raw string will have the exact same behavior.

Comment: Well, does the file actually exist in this path?

Comment: @DeepSpace..the question was updated...before OP was using single slashes.

Comment: Yes The file do exist on that path.

Comment: What part of "file not found" is hard to understand?

Comment: How can I create a dictionary in python from the given dataset which is in .csv format?

Answer (score 0):

When I downloaded it "as csv", it turned out it was downloaded as `.csv.csv`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It is working when I have tried to move the file in root project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move the file to your root project folder and call it by its name only? 
Using this way you can start checking if the file is reachable.

Comment: It's working fine now. How can I create a dictionary in python from the .csv file ?

Comment: If this answer helped you out to reach the solution, please mark it as useful.

Answer (score -2):

Once you solved the problem and asked for a code to read the CSV, here it is!

```
import csv

stock = []

with open('google_stock_data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        stock.append({
            'date': row[0],
            'open': row[1],
            'high': row[2],
            'low': row[3],
            'close': row[4],
            'volume': row[5],
            'adj_close': row[6]
        })
print(stock)
```

Read more in:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Hope it helps you!

Comment: What access link? OP is trying to open a file on their local machine.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G4sYrPtocF8eOoS4kEZtMQfMBTOc6luBu86Zm_vWiNA/edit#gid=1250910947

Comment: How will `csv` help to find a missing file?

Comment: The above method is also giving the following error.                        
                                                                                                          
            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    with open('eggs.csv',newline='') as csvfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'eggs.csv'